# Get the Json object from a array of Json objects using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I want to get the productLines for the prodType ULTRA for the Json array below. I get the array of maps and uses findIndexValues to get the index but
it doesn't work. What am I missing? I looked at similar examples which are less complex in structure and did not see much difference from what I'm attempting

Here is my data:

```
   def static modelData="""
{



  "models": [
    {

        "transactionId": "01-PROD0021",
        "prodCode": "ISN-2017WDE",
        "product": "VASCULAR DNNT",
        "prodType": "SDISCNT",
        "productLines": [

     {
                "productLineId": "ELECT-2221",
                "productDescriptor": "XTRA-SONIC DNNP",
                "unitPrice": "",
            },
            {
                "productLineId": "ELECT-2223",
                "productDescriptor": "HEADPH",
                "unitPrice": "1.33",
            }
        ]
    },


   {
        "transactionId": "01-PROD0024",
        "prodCode": "ISN-5543XDR",
        "product": "ULTRASOUND DEEP SONAR",
        "prodType": "ULTRA",
        "productLines": [
            {
                "productLineId": "MEDCN-XTR221",
                "productDescriptor": "ELECTRONIC RESPR",
                 "unitPrice": "2.44",
            },
            {
                "productLineId": "MEDCN-XTR376",
                "productDescriptor": "SPNG ELECTRONIC DEFIB",
                "unitPrice": "6.22",
            }
         }  
        ]
]
     }
"""
```

Here is my attempt:

```
  def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(modelData)

      // Find index of the prodCode with 'ULTRA'

         int [] vals=parsed.data.findIndexValues{

        it -> it.key=='prodType' &&  it.value=='ULTRA'}

        //Does not print anything

       vals?.each {println "Found an index! ${it}"  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out

```
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(modelData)
def vals = parsed.models.find{ it.prodType == 'ULTRA' }?.productLines
```

Comment: You may want `.findAll`, as `.find` will stop and return at the first match.

Comment: There is only ever going to be one which matches for a given prodType.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things wrong with the code:
 1. You loop through a "data" node, where there is none. Use `parsed.data`
 2. The each node is a map-like structure. Hence you check if the map contains a key `prodType` with value `ULTRA`. Use `it.prodType == 'ULTRA'`.

Pro-tip:
1. You can print what the data looks like on closures so that you will get to the solution quicker.